# When I split up my C++ class into a header and implementation I get 20 compiler errors which don't make sense

Tags: c++

I was splitting up my program into a header and implementation file per usual, however, when I tried to run the code, I got a ton of compile errors. This seems to be an issue with my computer or IDE, but I have not seen it before. This should be relatively simple as it is for a class project.
The code is as follows:

colorPicker.h

```
#pragma once
class colorPicker {
private: 
    string colorArray[7];
public: 
    colorPicker(); 
    void printAllColors(); 
    string randomColor(); 
};
```

colorPicker.cpp

```
#include "colorPicker.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std; 



colorPicker::colorPicker() {
    colorArray[0] = "Red"; 
    colorArray[1] = "Green";
    colorArray[2] = "Purple";
    colorArray[3] = "Yellow";
    colorArray[4] = "Orange";
    colorArray[5] = "Indigo";
    colorArray[6] = "Pink";
}

void colorPicker::printAllColors() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        cout << colorArray[i] << endl;
    }
}

string colorPicker::randomColor() {
    srand((unsigned)time(0)); 
    int j = 0; 
    j = rand() % 7; 
    return colorArray[j];
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "colorPicker.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    colorPicker p;
    p.printAllColors(); 
    cout << "Random Color: " << p.randomColor() << endl; 
    system("pause");
    return 0; 
 }
```

There are 20 errors given by the compiler, however, they all seem to be stemming from two undeclared identifiers which are most definitely declared. I am at a loss for what I could possibly do to fix it, and this project is due Sunday. Thank you.

Here are the errors
[Tons of Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QaMC.png)

Comment: Did you include the the header file in your cpp implementation?

Comment: `string colorArray` should be declared as `std::string colorArray` and you should include the header `<string>` from `colorPicker.h`.  Similarly, `randomColor()` should return `std::string`.

Comment: Danger Will Robinson! Danger! `#include "stdafx.h"` must come first. Everything before `#include "stdafx.h"` is ignored.

Answer (score 4):

You need `#include "colorPicker.h"` in `colorPicker.cpp`. Each .cpp file is handled basically independently by the compiler and they are all joined at the end by the "linker." When the compiler looks at `colorPicker.cpp` without an include of the corresponding header, it's at a loss as to the definition of all the classes you're working with.

Comment: Sorry, I copied my code wrong, I did have that included.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you are doing wrong.   I'll just pick on a couple.

Firstly, each header file you write should be self-contained - in the sense that, if it relies on content of some other headers, it includes that header.   If a compilation unit (a formal name for a source file with a .cpp in your case) includes your header, it should not have to include something else your header depends on.

Second, it is a bad idea for a header to rely on any using directive, such as `using namespace std`.   There are plenty of explanations of that available, so I won't repeat.

To understand the above, look at colorPicker.h

> ```
> class colorPicker {
>     private: 
>     string colorArray[7];
>     public: 
>       colorPicker(); 
>       void printAllColors(); 
>       string randomColor(); 
>  };
> ```

Firstly, this depends on `string`, but there is no definition of `string` visible in the header file.   Usage of that type depends on the standard header `<string>`.

Second, that `string` type is within namespace `std`.   So your header relies on the compilation unit (the source file that includes your header) having previously used a using directive i.e. `using namespace std`.

To fix these two problems, change the header to

```
 #ifndef SOME_MACRO_UNIQUE_TO_YOUR_COLOR_PICKER_HEADER
 #define SOME_MACRO_UNIQUE_TO_YOUR_COLOR_PICKER_HEADER

 #include <string>

 class colorPicker
 {
     private: 
         std::string colorArray[7];
     public: 
       colorPicker(); 
       void printAllColors(); 
       std::string randomColor(); 
 };

 #endif
```

(I've also done some minor changes of layout, since I have various reasons to prefer that.

However, the `#include <string>` means that this version will not fail to compile, as yours does, if it is included by a compilation unit that does not have `#include <string>`.

The usage of the fully qualified name `std::string`, rather than `string`, also means there is no dependence on the using directive `using namespace std`.   It also means compilation errors can't be triggered in your header if your compilation unit has another using directive.

I've also used an include guard, rather than `#pragma once`.   Although most modern compilers support `#pragma once`, it is actually not standard C++ (a `#pragma`, by definition in the standard, is a compiler-specific hook).  Include guards are supported in standard C++.

If you've done that, your code should mostly compile as is.   However, optionally, you may wish to

- remove the using directives `using namespace std` from your other files.    If you do that, you will need to change the definition of `colorPicker::randomColor()` in colorPicker.cpp so it returns the fully qualified type `std::string` rather than `string`.
- Remove `#include <string>` from files that have `#include "colorPicker.h"`.  This is possible, since colorPicker.h now includes `<string>`.   This step is optional, since there is no problem with including standard headers more than once in a compilation unit.

A few other notes

- In C++, although it is not a major concern, it is usually considered better to use include `<cstdio>` and `<cstdlib>` rather than the C headers `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`.
- Your code is calling `srand((unsigned)time(0))` whenever `colorPicker::randomColor()` is called.   It is better to only call it once in an entire program, not in a function that may be called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You may need add head file and  in colorPicker.h.
And the std namespace is needed while using string.

BTW, the header guards is recommended strongly.

```
#ifndef COLOR_PICKER_H
#define COLOR_PICKER_H

#pragma once

#include <string>

class colorPicker {
private:
    std::string colorArray[7];
public:
    colorPicker();
    void printAllColors();
    std::string randomColor();
};

#endif
```

Comment: `using` at global scope in a header file is a very bad idea. Just prepend all identifiers from the standard library with `std::`.

Comment: The text still mentions using declarations.

Answer (score 0):

A header file should be self-contained as far as `#include`s go. That means that you should be able to `#include` the header file *without* having to include other stuff before it!

Your `colorPicker.h` does not meet that requirement. It apparently uses `std::string` from the standard library but does not have an `#include <string>` on top, so everyone who uses `colorPicker.h` has to remember to put an `#include <string>` before it. That's pretty annoying.

Even worse, `colorPicker.h` refers to `std::string` as `string`, which implies a `using std::string;` or `using namespace std;` somewhere before any `#include "colorPicker.h"` line, and both of those are very bad coding style in C++, if not used in tighter scopes.

Here's how to fix the header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class colorPicker {
private: 
    std::string colorArray[7];
public: 
    colorPicker(); 
    void printAllColors(); 
    std::string randomColor(); 
};
```

As far as your *.cpp files go, I can see that you are using `#include "stdafx.h"`. Why? It's a non-standard Microsoft thing completely unnecessary in your case. You are also using it incorrectly. It must be the first include. Just remove it entirely.

Some other suggested cleanup:

- `using namespace std;` lines in *.cpp files is not as bad as in header files, but if I were you, I'd just get rid of it completely. Just use complete names. Say `std::cout`, not `cout`. And so on. It's just the most consistent way and it avoids a lot of trouble.
- You include a lot of headers which you don't need. For example, what's `<ctime>` for?
- Don't use `system("pause");`. Do not look for artificial ways of pausing a command-line program.